# О происхождении гоголевских выражений

Tags: этимология, литература

Здравствуйте, уважаемые организаторы сайта «Грамота.ру».

Обращаемся к вам с вопросом по творчеству Н.В. Гоголя. Скажите, пожалуйста, могли бы вы объяснить происхождение гоголевских выражений?

1. В тексте поэмы «Мертвые души» при обозначении взяток встречаем «рекомендательные письма за подписью князя Хованского». Окказионален ли этот описательный оборот или существовал ранее (может быть из фольклора)?
2. Почему слово фетюк ругательно по отношению к мужчине (из авторского примечания к речи Ноздрёва). Только ли фонетическая примета у этого слова? Этимологические словари дают однозначные ответы по отрицательной коннотации.
3. Из речи Ноздрёва: «попользоваться насчет клубнички». Это выражение введено в дискурс Н.В. Гоголем или же оно интерлингвально?
4. И последнее: почему колода стоит того, чтобы назвать ее именем? Из речи людей играющих в карты? (Аделаида Ивановна)

Answer (score 1):

Вы попутали. Это не грамота.ру. И здесь более занимаются языком, не литературой. Но я попробую ответить. В той мере, насколько ваши вопросы понятны. По сути же ответы есть в комментариях к большунсву изданий.

~1. "Оборот", конечно же, окказионален. Вряд ли бы Гоголь позаимствовал его у кого-то. Во всяком случае никаких указаний на использование его кем-то до написания "Мертвых душ" я не знаю.

"...рекомендательные письма за подписью князя Хованского... — ироническое название взяток; подпись князя А. Н. Хованского (1771—1857), управляющего государственным
ассигнационным банком, стояла на всех ассигнациях."

~2. Фетюк - от "фита", греческая буква, проникшая в русский алфавит, абсолютно ненужная с самого начала, использовалась только в некоторых греческих именах. Помимо этой ненужности ассоциировалась с неуклюжим, никчемным человеком ещё и своим внешним видом.

~3. Согласно Виноградову не только оборот, но и самом слово "клюбничка" в этом значении введено в оборот Гоголем.

"Гоголь в «Мертвых душах» пускает в оборот новое значение слова клубничка: `что-нибудь скабрезное, эротическое, нескромное'". (История слов)

~4. Это из "Игроков", пьеса написана другим языком, да не разобрана на цитаты как "Мертвые души", поэтому значение вряд ли переносно. Утешительный прямо говорит, что колода **носит имя как человек**. В целом шулера просто договариваются об использовании условного названия в своём воровском языке. Это в каком-то смысле можно считать предшественником современной фени.

Comment: Здесь занимаются и языком, и литературой. Просто, по литературе задают меньше вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

Князя Хованского рекомендательные письма
Разг. Устар. 1. Деньги. 2. Взятки. /em> Буквально — «за подписью книязя Хованского». А. Н. Хованский (1771–1857) — князь, управлявший государственным ассигнационным банком. БМС 1998, 267.

Большой словарь русских поговорок. — М: Олма Медиа Групп. В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина. 2007.

У Гоголя: “Проситель … засовывал руку в карман, с тем чтобы вытащить оттуда известные рекомендательные письма за подписью князя Хованского, **как выражаются у нас на Руси…**”

Выделенные мной слова указывают на то, что это выражение было в ходу до "Мёртвых душ".  Будучи  автором этого выражения,Гоголь вряд ли бы  сделал эту приписку,

Comment: Будь выражение общеизвестным, "приписка" бы не понадобилась.
А так Гоголь одновременно вроде бы как снимает с себя ответственность за употребление возможно неподцензурной идиомы и обвинения в возможном "плагиате".

Comment: Вот интересное объянение того, зачем Гоголь это делает:

Эффект остранения, создаваемый при переводе, оказывается конгениальным поэтике оригинала в тех фрагментах, где сам Гоголь моделирует установку на остранение. **Он делает это с помощью формул цитирования, маркирующих введение «чужого» слова в авторский текст. Ср. фразу «известные рекомендательные письма за подписью князя Хованского, как выражаются у нас на Руси» (231).**
Гоголь как бы перестает говорить от своего лица и делегирует авторство высказывания анонимному «русскому народу»...